# Getting a "ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis" when trying to download financial data from yahoo

Tags: python, pandas

So, I want to compare Bitcoin Data to the S&P500,
This is what the code looks like

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
import datetime
import backtrader as bt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

This is to import the necessary libraries

```
tickers = ['^bvsp', '^gspc', 'btc-usd']
mydata = pd.DataFrame()
for t in tickers:
    mydata[t] = wb.DataReader(t, data_source='yahoo', start='2019-1-1')['Adj Close']
```

This is to get all the financial data I need and put it into a single dataframe. Take out btc-usd, and it seems ok, but I really wanted to compare btc-usd to the other two, and later run a more complicated backtest.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer yfinance for this purpose. You can find details here: https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance

You can implement want you need in your question quite easy.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
```

Then create a list of your tickers and download.

```
tickers = ["^bvsp", "^gspc", "btc-usd"]
yf.download(tickers, start="2020-05-01")
```

Result in one dataframe:

```
[*********************100%***********************]  3 of 3 completed
           Adj Close                        Close                     \
             BTC-USD     ^BVSP    ^GSPC   BTC-USD     ^BVSP    ^GSPC   
Date                                                                   
2020-05-01  8864.767       nan 2830.710  8864.767       nan 2830.710   
2020-05-02  8988.597       nan      nan  8988.597       nan      nan   
2020-05-03  8897.469       nan      nan  8897.469       nan      nan   
2020-05-04  8912.654 78876.000 2842.740  8912.654 78876.000 2842.740   
2020-05-05  9003.070 79471.000 2868.440  9003.070 79471.000 2868.440   
2020-05-06  9268.762 79064.000 2848.420  9268.762 79064.000 2848.420   
2020-05-07  9951.519 78119.000 2881.190  9951.519 78119.000 2881.190   
2020-05-08  9842.666 80263.000 2929.800  9842.666 80263.000 2929.800   
2020-05-09  9593.896       nan      nan  9593.896       nan      nan   
2020-05-10  8756.431       nan      nan  8756.431       nan      nan   
2020-05-11  8601.796 79065.000 2930.190  8601.796 79065.000 2930.190   
2020-05-12  8804.478 77872.000 2870.120  8804.478 77872.000 2870.120
```

There are quite a lot of options like getting back just one column, start end dates, time frequency. Yfinance quite easy to use. Just have a look at the docs on git.

Answer (score 0):

yea use yfinance like this so that you just replace how you use

'data = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)'

This can be replaced with

yf.download(ticker, start="2020-05-01")

and then import yfinance after pip installing it in anaconda/your console
import yfinanace as yf

:)

Comment: Could you please edit your answer. Right now the order is confusing and please add a code block to make it easier to see what is code and what is a comment.